# How to add Google Maps in Flutter Forms to ask user to select Location

Tags: flutter, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on a Flutter project where I have to add user details as well as location of their mosques so how can I implement in this form using google maps in Flutter?

Which are resources should I have to follow to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you must add the Google Maps Package to your pubspec.yaml https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter .
2. Get the Google map API key from the Google Cloud Console [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Google%20Maps%20Platform%20%3E%20Credentials%20page.&text=On%20the%20Credentials%20page%2C%20click,Click%20Close](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Google%20Maps%20Platform%20%3E%20Credentials%20page.&text=On%20the%20Credentials%20page%2C%20click,Click%20Close). This Totorial maybe helpful for you https://blog.logrocket.com/google-maps-flutter/ .
3. Add the google map widget in your code where the user can select the location of their mosques. Use 'onMapCreated'callbacks and add the markers to check the location of mosques.
4. Add form fields for user details.https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html , and after the form submission you can save user details along with the details of the mosques. this tutorial may be helpful for you https://blog.logrocket.com/google-maps-flutter/ .